# Insert Long BLOB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a file around 25mb. In my server max_allowed_packet
    value is 16mb, I cann't change the server configuration. How can I
    Insert a file into mysql blob? I have used this code in my local
    host. It Works fine. But this is not working in my online server.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO FILES_DATA (FileData) VALUES (?)"); 
$null = NULL; 
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null); 
$fp = fopen("Wildlife.wmv", "r");

echo('<br>fp='.$fp); 
while (!feof($fp)) { 
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192)); 
} 
fclose($fp); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Sql to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'files_data' ( 
    'Id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'FileData' longblob, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('Id') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question here is why you want to insert a 25MB file to a database. Use the file system and sore the path to the file in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround - use some BLOB fields to store the file. Split your 25MB file to two byte arrays: 16MB + 9MB, and insert them into the table using HEX-notation, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO table files(id, data1, data2) VALUES(1, 0x616263..., 0x78797A...)
```

Comment: I have used the method - split the file and insert in multiple rows, I haven't used this , i will try. Thanks.